# solve $\int(1+x)e^x/(2+x)^2\,dx$

Tags: calculus

To solve:
$$
I=\int \frac{(1+x)e^x}{(2+x)^2} \,dx.
$$ 
We have a ready formula as 
$$
\int e^x[f(x)+f'(x)]\,dx= e^x f(x).
$$
My question is how to find $f(x)$ from the given function in question such that we have $f'(x)$ available with us?

Answer (score 4):

$$ \frac{1+x}{(x+2)^2} = \frac{x+2 -1}{(x+2)^2} = \frac{1}{x+2} - \frac{1}{(x+2)^2} = \frac{1}{x+2} + \left( \frac{1}{x+2} \right)'$$